# < and > in node value problem in creating XML using DOM Document

Tags: php, xml

Im creating a script to parse json into XML using DOM Document. I encountered problem when I want to put < and > inside node value in createElement part. the `<` and `>` is converted into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and I want it to be stay as it is.

How can I make it stay as it is?

Here my current code:

```
    $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $dom->xmlVersion = '1.0';
    $dom->formatOutput = true;

    $root = $dom->createElement('questions', "<![CDATA[what animal walk above the wave?]]>");

    ....

    $dom->save('file.xml');
```

my XML result:

```
<question>&lt;![CDATA[what animal walk above the wave?]]&gt;</question>
```

I'm expecting:

```
<question><![CDATA[what animal walk above the wave?]]></question>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tree model of XML and the serialized representation are quite different things. In the tree model you create nodes with string values; generation of markup happens when the tree is serialized to lexical XML. So you can't put lexical XML in the DOM and expect it to survive serialization.

Answer (score -1):

The second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` (and `SimpleXMLElement::addChild()`) as well as `DOMElement::$nodeValue` have the same weird behaviour. They escape `<` and `>`, but not `&`. To avoid the problems in DOM you can use `DOMDocument::createTextNode()` and `DOMNode::$textContent`. CDATA Sections are a type of node, you will need to use `DOMDocument::createCDATASection()` for them.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$examples = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('examples'));
$examples
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('one'))
  // append an explcit text node - original DOM approach
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('foo > bar'));
$examples
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('two'))
  // write textContent - DOM Level 3 shortcut
  ->textContent = 'foo > bar';
$examples
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('three'))
  // add CDATA sectiom
  ->appendChild($document->createCDATASection('foo > bar'));

$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<examples>
  <one>foo &gt; bar</one>
  <two>foo &gt; bar</two>
  <three><![CDATA[foo > bar]]></three>
</examples>
```

Comment: I wouldn’t call this a bug. `createElement` is simply the wrong method to create an element with CDATA content, there is a dedicated method for that for a reason. The manual for `createElement` explicitly states, _“The value is used verbatim except that the < and > entity references will escaped”_ - so this is an absolute case of “works as designed” here.

Comment: Kind of, `createElement()` has no second argument in the W3C standard and `nodeValue` behaves not like defined for elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue I changed the wording.

Comment: Okay, yeah, if you go by specified W3C DOM methods, I see your point.